# Cross Account Access problem in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need help to understand the cross-account S3 policy better:

I have two AWS accounts account A and account B. Account A has a user (user A) with role A, and Account B has a user B with role B.

I had User B create a S3 bucket and S3 policies **In account A**. The S3 bucket has the following configuration:

1. Disable using public ACL.
2. Allow anyone in the world `GetObject` from this bucket **by S3 Policy**
3. Allow Role B to have full access to the bucket and its objects **by S3 Policy**

Then user B uploads object without any ACL to the bucket.

As a result, the objects uploaded by User B cannot be accessed by User A nor public user with a 403 Error.
If User A uploads an object to the bucket. That Object is accessible.

Could anyone help explain the cross-account policy/identity problem here? why did I get a 403 error?

PS: I understand this is not the recommended way to achieve whatever I might want to do. However, I'd like take this example/opportunity to get better understanding the way that cross account S3 policies works.

Comment: "As a result, the objects uploaded by User B cannot be accessed with a 403 Error." - By whom?

Comment: You need to apply the acl `bucket-owner-full-control`, otherwise your bucket policy does not apply to those objects that it does not own.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you for the reply, but who is the bucket owner? how that affect policy apply?

Comment: The bucket owner is the account that the S3 bucket lives in.

Comment: See my approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68153829/aws-emr-cross-account-s3-bucket-access-approach-with-cross-account-iam-roles